# Comparing two large lists in java

Tags: java, java-7

I have to Array lists with 1000 objects in each of them. I need to remove all elements in Array list 1 which are there in Array list 2. Currently I am running 2 loops which is resulting in 1000 x 1000 operations in worst case.

```
List<DataClass> dbRows = object1.get("dbData");
List<DataClass> modifiedData = object1.get("dbData");
List<DataClass> dbRowsForLog = object2.get("dbData");
for (DataClass newDbRows : dbRows) {
            boolean found=false;
            for (DataClass oldDbRows : dbRowsForLog) {
                if (newDbRows.equals(oldDbRows)) {
                    found=true;
                    modifiedData.remove(oldDbRows);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

public class DataClass{
    private int categoryPosition;
    private int subCategoryPosition;
    private Timestamp lastUpdateTime;
    private String lastModifiedUser;
    // + so many other variables 
    
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        DataClass dataClassRow = (DataClass) o;
        return  categoryPosition == dataClassRow.categoryPosition
                && subCategoryPosition == dataClassRow.subCategoryPosition && (lastUpdateTime.compareTo(dataClassRow.lastUpdateTime)==0?true:false)
                && stringComparator(lastModifiedUser,dataClassRow.lastModifiedUser);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "DataClass[categoryPosition="+categoryPosition+",subCategoryPosition="+subCategoryPosition
                +",lastUpdateTime="+lastUpdateTime+",lastModifiedUser="+lastModifiedUser+"]";
    }
    
    public static boolean stringComparator(String str1, String str2){
         return (str1 == null ? str2 == null : str1.equals(str2));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 31 * hash + (int) categoryPosition;
    hash = 31 * hash + (int) subCategoryPosition
    hash = 31 * hash + (lastModifiedUser == null ? 0 : lastModifiedUser.hashCode());
    return hash;
    }
}
```

The best work around i could think of is create 2 sets of strings by calling tostring() method of DataClass and compare string. It will result in 1000 (for making set1) + 1000 (for making set 2) + 1000 (searching in set ) = 3000 operations. I am stuck in Java 7. Is there any better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why not let the DB do the heavy lifting?

Comment: Do you need to maintain any kind of order in the remaining items?  Could you use sets here?

Comment: Obviously there isn't (apart from some constant factor, if the database implementation is very efficient) -- you need about that much time to read it anyway. If *that* is not fast enough then you might want to clarify what problem are you trying to solve and we might be able to find some more efficient way to store your data.

Comment: @ScaryWombat db guys wont approve to do this at db layer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen lists are not ordered. yes i can create new sets

Comment: Can there be duplicates in either list?

Comment: Does `DataClass` implement `hashCode` and `equals`? If it does, you can create a `HashSet<DataClass>` using the second list, then `firstList.removeAll(theSet)`.

Comment: @user202729 yeah I guess we cant do this in any less than 3000 operations. I have no control in how we store data as it is used in so many places so cant modify it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no duplicates

Comment: Still, why is 3000 operations a large amount? What are your requirements? Shouldn't computers nowadays be able to do it in a microsecond?

Comment: @user202729 yeah I guess 3000 should be fine, this method might be called so many times in a minute, just want to have best performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let Java's builtin collections classes handle <s>most of</s> the optimization for you by taking advantage of a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). The complexity of its `contains` method is O(1). I would highly recommend looking up how it achieves this because it's very interesting.

```
List<DataClass> a = object1.get("dbData");
HashSet<DataClass> b = new HashSet<>(object2.get("dbData"));
a.removeAll(b);
return a;
```

And it's all done for you.

**EDIT: caveat**

In order for this to work, `DataClass` needs to implement [`Object::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). Otherwise, you can't use any of the hash-based collection algorithms.

**EDIT 2: implementing `hashCode`**

An object's hash code does not need to change every time an instance variable changes. The hash code only needs to reflect the *instance variables that determine equality*.

For example, imagine each object had a unique field `private final UUID id`. In this case, you could determine if two objects were the same by simply testing the `id` value. Fields like `lastUpdateTime` and `lastModifiedUser` would provide *information about the object*, but two instances with the same `id` would refer to the same object, *even if the `lastUpdateTime` and `lastModifiedUser` of each were different*.

The point is that if you really want to want to optimize this, include as few fields as possible in the hash computation. From your example, it seems like `categoryPosition` and `subCategoryPosition` *might* be enough.

Whatever fields you choose to include, the simplest way to compute a hash code from them is to use [`Objects::hash`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...)) rather than running the numbers yourself.

Comment: I have added hashCode implementation to DataClass (edited question) is it enough. Thank you very much I will try this.

Comment: @Ravi added some advice about hashCode

Comment: Thank you for sharing best practices. I will make modifications to my code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Set A-B operation(only retain elements in Set A that are not in Set B = A-B)

If using Set is fine then we can do like below. We can use ArrayList as well in place of Set but in AL case for each element to remove/retain check it needs to go through an entire other list scan.

```
Set<DataClass> a = new HashSet<>(object1.get("dbData"));
Set<DataClass> b = new HashSet<>(object2.get("dbData"));
a.removeAll(b);
```

If ordering is needed, use TreeSet.

**Try to return a set from object1.get("dbData") and object2.get("dbData") that skips one more intermediate collection creation.**